# Boxlayout stretch my Jpanels

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, stretch, boxlayout

Hey (: This is my first time asking help on this forum so I hope I have done everything correctly

Okay my problem is what I have marked with red. My JPanel uses a Boxlayout with BoxLayout.Y_AXIS orientation. I guess that is not the right choise. I don't want my JPanel(online users), my JSeperator and my other JPanel(admin) to be apart of eachother. I want them to stack directly under eachother.

Pic of GUI: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10049103/notcool.png

I have heard that I should be able to use some kind of "glue" but could not get that to work as intended. I also heard that I had to use GridBagLayout but that seems very complicated and I would really like if there is an easier way.

Here is the code for the marked JPanel (don't know if needed):

```
package Client;

import Server.User;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;

/**
 *
 * @author Sune
 */
public class OnlineUsersPanel extends JPanel {
private UserWindow owner; public void setOwner(UserWindow uw) { owner = uw; }
private HashMap<String, ShowUserPanel> userPanels = new HashMap<String, ShowUserPanel>();

public OnlineUsersPanel() {
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    this.add(addStart());
    this.add(new JSeparator());
    System.out.println("OnlineUsersPanel con called");
}

void addUser(User user) {
    ShowUserPanel newPanel = new ShowUserPanel(owner, user.getUserName());
    userPanels.put(user.getUserName(), newPanel);
    this.add(newPanel);
    owner.updateGUI();
}

void deleteUser(User user) {
    ShowUserPanel toRemove;

    for (Iterator i = userPanels.keySet().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        String tempUserName = (String) i.next();
        if (tempUserName.equals(user.getUserName())) {
            toRemove = userPanels.remove(tempUserName);
            this.remove(toRemove);
            System.out.println("Fundet og fjernet");
            break;
        }
    }
}

private JPanel addStart() {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(new JLabel("Online Users:"), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    p.add(new JLabel("mute:"), BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    return p;
}
```

I hope someone can learn me how to use that glue properly or tell me the good way to do this (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: changed to an answer:

The panels are right on top of each other. The question is what kind of layout is being used by the container holding the two JPanels? Also are you doing to display many users? Do you need a JList or JTable there? Can you show a picture of what you want the gui to look like, and show it when there are a typical number of users. Also consider creating and posting an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org). This would take a bit of work on your part, but would be well worth it.

**Edit 1:**
On further review of your image, I suggest that you use a JTable here with "Online Users" and "Mute" as your column headings and with the stuff you currently show below, the Admin and the checkbox as a row of the JTable. Put it in a JScrollPane and display it where you're currently displaying it.

Comment: Thank you for the answear and sorry i didn't provide enough information.
So here is a pic of my program doing as I want to (:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10049103/working.png (can't upload pictures as new user :/ )
I followed your advice and checked my LayoutManger. I then realised that I gave it a new LayoutMangaer everytime I added a user. Apparently that made the layout screw up

Comment: @Sune: definitely you want to use a JTable.

Comment: The only reason I didn't pick a JTable is because I have no idea how to use one :p But yes guess that would have been an easier/better solution

Comment: @Sune: It still is a better solution, and it's not that hard to use. You'll just need to go through the tutorial on it. I do differ with the tutorial in one aspect in that I recommend that you use a DefaultTableModel for your JTable's model rather than an AbstractTableModel. The DefaultTableModel is much easier to use.

Comment: Thanks I will try use a table instead.

Answer (score 2):

after adding the two panels to the boxlayout do

```
add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
```

this will shrink those two panels to their preferred sizes, and put the space below them.

Comment: I could not get that to work unfortunately but thank you for answearing (:
The glue only make my other Panels( usernames ) move up a little. It behaves as if I inserted another invisible user. They just share all the space available.